# Why do cloundfront signed urls and cookies require account root?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

According to [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-trusted-signers.html#private-content-creating-cloudfront-key-pairs) for generating key pairs for use with [Cloudfront Signed URLs and Signed Cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html) root credentials are required to either generate or upload key pairs. Other key pairs used with AWS, such as EC2 authentication key pairs, do not require special elivated root credentials. Is there something special about signing this category object (urls, cookies) that requires special authority?

The closest I can get to an answer is by way of metaphor to other types of proofs of control, such as when DNS TXT entries are used to prove control of a domain during a certificate signing request. In my mind this still falls short of requiring root credentials in the case at hand and I do not see how requiring root proves ownership of anything substantial over and above what a standard IAM user proves.

I'd appreciate any insights. Thanks for reading.

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe my question is precisely about **managing information technology systems in a business environment** because without the historical context, which michael-sqlbot supplied with his helpful answer to the question, sysadmins are left to infer that there is something unique about the security requirements of Cloudfront. Elsewhere in the AWS eco system IAM users are used for day-to-day activities and best practices explicitly recommend: [Limit root user access to your resources](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/security-best-practices/).

Comment: I believe you're correct in your assessment.

Comment: While I agree that this is about managing information techonology systems in a business environment, I would still have voted to close the question. This is a decision made by AWS about their environment, and the reasons behind it should be asked of AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no obvious reason why this **still** works the way it does... but when CloudFront signed URLs became available [in 2009](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudfront-feature-private-content/), there was no such thing as an IAM user.  IAM wasn't generally available [until 2011](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/iam-identity-access-management/).

Originally, the root user was the only user in each AWS account.  Why this design wasn't subsequently changed to support an IAM user being granted permission to administer these keypairs is neither readily apparent nor documented.